# MariaDB connector OBC Build- Driver manager was not found

Tags: cmake, mariadb, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build the RPM from the source https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-odbc/3.0.8/ on SUSE Linux
following mariadb homepage
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-connectorodbc-from-source/#building-mariadb-connectorodbc
However, it results in the following error "Driver Manager was not found"
.

```
 + cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCONC_WITH_UNIT_TESTS=Off '- 
 DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=-I/usr/local/incude/mariadb -L/usr/local/lib'
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.1
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
 -- Detecting C compile features
 -- Detecting C compile features - done
 -- There is no Connector/C sub-project folder, linking against libmariadb installed on the system
 -- Looking for floor
 -- Looking for floor - not found
 -- Looking for floor in m
 -- Looking for floor in m - found
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:180 (MESSAGE):
 Driver Manager was not found
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Noting a typo in your path: `/usr/local/incude/mariadb`. If should be `include*`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to build the connector on platforms other than i686/x86_64?

I encountered the same issue when I am building it on AWS t4g (ARM architecture). I have succeeded to get rid of this error by providing the correct location of headers:

`DM_DIR=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCONC_WITH_UNIT_TESTS=Off -DCONC_WITH_MSI=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .`

The correct location of `DM_DIR` may vary depends on your architecture. (In my case: `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` for AWS EC2 t4g instance with Debian 10)

Reference: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-268